# Does gpg-agent.conf support environment variables for extra-socket option and in general?

Tags: gnupg, gpg-agent

I'm using gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.3.4 on M1 Mac, OS X 12.1. I want to use the `extra-socket` option in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`. If I have

```
extra-socket $HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

and run `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent; and gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`, the agent fails to start.

```
gpg-connect-agent: no running gpg-agent - starting '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.4/bin/gpg-agent'
gpg-connect-agent: error running '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.4/bin/gpg-agent': exit status 2
gpg-connect-agent: failed to start gpg-agent '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.4/bin/gpg-agent': General error
gpg-connect-agent: can't connect to the gpg-agent: General error
gpg-connect-agent: error sending standard options: No agent running
```

If I hardcode the absolute path for the socket

```
extra-socket /Users/dxia/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

the agent starts successfully and works.

```
gpg-connect-agent: no running gpg-agent - starting '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.4/bin/gpg-agent'
gpg-connect-agent: waiting for the agent to come up ... (5s)
gpg-connect-agent: connection to the agent established
OK
```

Are env vars not supported for `extra-socket`? I'm confused because an env var for `log-file` in `gpg-agent.conf` works fine.

```
log-file $HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.log
```